# How to work with hyperlink and submit buttons together in Foundation Zurb CSS

Tags: css, forms, button, zurb-foundation

I really like the Option Button found in the ZURB building block library here: http://zurb.com/building-blocks/option-button 
However, I am almost always working with 1 x normal hyperlink button and a submit button. I'm finding this is causing me headaches wherever I try to have neat rows of buttons that should look the same. What additional CSS would get this 'Option Button' to work as desired when working with an input submit class ?

My HTML is pretty straightforward and looks like this:

```
<form name="article_selection" action="single-article-view.php" method="post">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="medium-6 columns">
                <div class="wrapper">
                     <label>READ MORE</label>

                    <a href="<?php echo $article_URL; ?>" class="inside">Read on another website</a>


                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $article_ID; ?>" name="article_ID" />
                    <input type="submit" class="inside" name="<?php echo $article_ID; ?>" value="Read on this website" />

                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

In this scenario the 2nd half of the option button is malformed. 
I can't update an image to display due to reputation restrictions (seriously?)

```html
<a href="http://s96.photobucket.com/user/indoanalytics/media/Button_Problem_zpszhgpvzbt.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i96.photobucket.com/albums/l185/indoanalytics/Button_Problem_zpszhgpvzbt.png" border="0" alt=" photo Button_Problem_zpszhgpvzbt.png"/></a>
```

The CSS as per the building blocks option button (linked to above) is:

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #008cba;
  border-radius: 999px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 50px;

}

.wrapper:hover {
  border: none;
  background-color: #008cba;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;

}

.wrapper:hover .inside {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 22px;
  float: left;

}

.wrapper:hover .inside:hover {
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

}

.wrapper:hover label {
  display: none;

}

.wrapper .inside {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 9999;

}

.wrapper label {

  padding: 16px;
  color: #008cba;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;

}
```

**Update:** I also have separate button stylings before the above in the my CSS which may be causing the problem.

```
.topic-button { 

        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 1;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background: #009fd9;
        color: #fff;
        box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4) 0 1px 0 inset;
        border-color: #008cbf;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 5px 6px;
        margin-top: 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-topic-button { 
        width:99%;
        background: #444444;
        border:none;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 1;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 2px;
        margin-top: 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
```

I have attempted applying CSS from the above to:

```
.wrapper button[type="submit"] {}
.wrapper input[type="submit"] {}
```

For both I have copied the .inline CSS from the zurb building blocks as well as tried resetting CSS values back to zero in both, but no luck.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow! Please make a Fiddle, it will help us to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like. It looks fine here: http://codeply.com/go/5NG5DIP4u5

Comment: It appears as if the css for the submit button is inheriting styles. At first @Skelly your code worked perfectly but now I get the same as on my site. I think a different submit button class is screwing with things - will update question to include more details.